# asp web app razor2 onclick automatically run once page is freshed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Razor v2 VS2012, as for testing purpose i loaded a new website from default template.
now, i have following link with in a table.

```
   <a href="" onclick="@myApp.CancelOrder(SellOrders[0].Key)"      id="@SellOrders[0].Key">@SellOrders[0].Value.Amount.ToString()</a>
```

i want it to be a link when user clicks on the link, myApp.cancelorder is invoked and an order is canceled. 
somehow, this automatically runs when page reloads or submit button is clicked.

anybody help?

thanks

Comment: comment out that line - I don't think its being called from that line

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the CancelOrder method will be executed as soon as the visitor loads the page.

The onclick attribute must be a plain javascript string, which is executed when the user clicks the link in the browser.

Comment: so in that case, how could i make it call CancelOrder method from a Link when user clicks on it? i mean beside using javascript

Comment: if have to use javascript, how can we do it in this case? thanks

Comment: I cant seem to invoke helper method from javascript

Comment: ok i know whats wrong, the href="" need to change to href="#". question closed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try change `href=""` for `href="#"`